# How do I migrate COMPANY.visualstudio.com account from pay-as-you-go to CSP

Tags: azure-devops

We would like to connect our COMPANY.visualstudio.com account to an Azure subscription under CSP programme (for billing and user management). What steps should we follow?

Currently, the COMPANY.visualstudio.com account is linked to an Azure subscription under pay-as-you-go programme. We are in the Western Europe region, and the COMPANY.visualstudio.com account was created in 2015 (visualstudio.com wasn't available under CSP in our region during that period). During that period it was required that the owing account (to link to a pay-as-you-go Azure subscription) is a Microsoft account, therefore, current owing account is still a Microsoft account.

Screenshot of the organisation setting page:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to [Change the Azure subscription your Azure DevOps organization uses for billing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/change-azure-subscription?view=vsts)

On the other hand, this document may benefit to you: [What types of Azure subscriptions can be used to buy Azure DevOps?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/vsts-billing-faq?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#q-what-types-of-azure-subscriptions-can-be-used-to-buy-azure-devops)